# Завершение и сохранение данных в потоках

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Есть 3 потока, которые выполняют некую функцию. В функции изменяются списки. Стоит задача, по команде останавливать все потоки, а изменения в этих списках сохранять.

Код

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=final, args=(block1, block_out1,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=final, args=(block2, block_out2,))
t3 = threading.Thread(target=final, args=(block3, block_out3,))
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
```

Как я понимаю, мне нужен 4 поток, который будет отслеживать `input` команды остановки. Как завершить потоки и сохранить данные? Была идея завершать процесс `python` через `os`, но это выглядит, как не очень элегантное решение.

Comment: Нехорошо удалять свои вопросы после получения ответа (；⌣̀_⌣́)

Comment: @nomnoms12 извиняюсь :) просто у меня все работало, я скопировал старый код. Моя невнимательность меня погубит, дал Вам репутацию тут.

Comment: Потоки завершить нельзя просто так... Отслеживайте Event() внутри потока

Comment: Можно пример функции final в общих чертах?

Comment: @eri в `final` создается объект класса и вызывается его метод. Метод обрабатывает некоторые данные из списка `block`, удаляет их из этого списка и добавляет в `block_out`. Задача в том, чтобы в любое время можно было завершить программу командой, а потом возобновить работу программы с последней итерации по списку `block`. Как последнюю часть осуществить я примерно понимаю, но как грамотно остановить потоки не знаю.

Comment: Вот внутри цикла на каждой итерации опрашивай event если эвент стоит - райзи эксепшан. В основном потоке join-ы

Comment: @eri я до этого никогда с потоками не работал, поэтому не очень понимаю суть написанного)
можно поподробнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def final(b_in, b_out, ev) :
    for a in b_in:
        if ev.is_set():
            break # или raise Exception('canceled') 
        # Работа

event = threading.Event()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=final, args=(block1, block_out1, event)) 
t1.start()

if input() == 'stop' :
    event.set()

t1.join()

# вывод
```

Както так

Пс. пишу с телефона..

В асинхронных заданиях asincio.Task можно вызывать исключение в любом месте из основного потока - но это другое

Comment: Попробую, спасибо. Еще такой вопрос, получается этот ивент будет для всех потоков? И эти 3 потока работают не синхронно из-за того, что там решается капча, а время ее решения отличается, получается при вводе команды каждый поток остановится, когда дойдет до этого места в цикле, верно?

Comment: да, когда дойдет до этой строчки. цикл прерывается break после проверки евента, а райз прерывает весь тред